# How do I add a random Timer Loop in JavaFX Scene Builder?

Tags: java, javafx, timer, scenebuilder, timertask

I'm programming my first little "Computer Game" as a school project and it's a Beat 'em up, a Fighting Game, where 2 Dudes beat each other up, pretty simple game.
I need to implement a Method, which makes the enemy attack the Player at random intervals, while the program is running and you are able to input attacks etc.

I made an AI-Method and to be honest, I had some troubles before, but it worked while testing 9/10 times.
I added a Timer, which restarts all the time with another random number to start the timertask at random intervals to make the enemy more unpredictable in my game.
I also added some Sound Effects and a check, if you have lost all your hitpoints and lost the game.
Damage is done to a Healthbar, which is a []Char Array. This gets calculated in my "DamageMachen()" Method.

Now my game is finished and I want to implement that method into my controllerClass, but as soon as the method gets startet, my program crashes :(

Does anyone know any solution for fixing that problem or maybe another method I could use, with the same funcions as mine?

In my Test-Class, this AI-Method works... not good, but it works. Sometimes the AI stops, I think because of the random numbers, but it worked 9/10 times. I just couldn't fix the problem. I tried to change the range of random numbers and sometimes it was even worse, so I picked the numbers between 1 and 3 seconds, which worked the best for me.

When I implemented that Method in my game, the game either crashes, or I can't input anything else, because I believe, that AI-Method first has to finish, but how I programmed it, it will never finish, until the game is done.

If you have some questions about my code, please let me know. It's my first time asking a question here, so I hope what I showed you is enough to see my problem.

```
// KI-Methode THIS IS MY MAIN PROBLEM. I'LL ALSO ADD THE OTHER METHODS DOWN 
//THERE JUST TO HELP YOU VISUALIZE MY WHOLE CODE

public void KI() {

    long interval = 0;

    gewinnErmitteln();
    boolean verloren = noob();
    int start = 0;
    int zaehler = 0;

    while (gewonnen == false && verloren == false) {
        try {
            Random r = new Random();
            double randomValue = 1 + (3 - 1) * r.nextDouble();

            ki = new Timer();
            interval = (long) (randomValue * 1000);

            TimerTask kitask = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {

                    damageMachen(damageNormal);

                    // Visualisieren TEST
                    //visualisieren();

                    done = true;
                    ki.cancel();
                }
            };
            if (start == zaehler) {
                ki.schedule(kitask, interval);
                zaehler++;
            } else if (done == true) {
                done = false;
                ki.schedule(kitask, interval);
            }

// THIS METHOD JUST CHECKS, IF YOU EITHER HAVE WON OR LOST BY CHECKING; IF THE //[]CHAR ARRAY IS FULL (All Health lost)

            gewinnErmitteln();
            verloren = noob();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION: " + e);
        }
        continue;
    }
    if (verloren == true) {
        ki.cancel();
        try {

            AudioInputStream sad = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                    new File("MySoundHere"));

            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(sad);
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



// HERE IS THE METHOD, WHICH I USE TO CALCULATE THE DAMAGE OF ENEMY ATTACKS
// DAMAGE GETS DONE TO A HEALTHBAR, WHICH IS A []CHAR-ARRAY

// Damage-Methoden

public void damageMachen(int damage) {
    int damagedone = 0;
    int thisdamage = damage;
    int focusdamage = 2;
    int focusdamagedone = 0;

    if (blocken == false) {

        // AUDIO

        for (int i = 0; i < lebensbalkenValue; i++) {
            if (thisdamage != damagedone && lebensbalken[i] == ' ') {
                lebensbalken[i] = 'I';
                damagedone++;
                try {

                    AudioInputStream punch = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                            "MyOtherAudio"));

                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clip.open(punch);
                    clip.start();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = fokusValue - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (focusdamage != focusdamagedone && fokusbalken[i] == 'I') {
                fokusbalken[i] = ' ';
                focusdamagedone++;
                try {

                    AudioInputStream punch = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                            "YetAnotherAudioClip"));

                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clip.open(punch);
                    clip.start();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        int focusdone = 0;
        int thisfocus = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < fokusValue; i++) {
            if (thisfocus != focusdone && fokusbalken[i] == ' ') {
                fokusbalken[i] = 'I';
                focusdone++;

            }
        }
    }
}

// MY CONSTRUCTOR

public Model() {

    lebensbalken = new char[lebensbalkenValue];

    for (int i = 0; i < lebensbalkenValue; i++) {
        lebensbalken[i] = ' ';
    }

    fokusbalken = new char[fokusValue];

    for (int i = 0; i < fokusValue; i++) {
        fokusbalken[i] = ' ';
    }
}

// MY CONTROLLER CLASS, I INITIALIZE THE AI METHOD RIGHT AT THE BEGINNING

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    javaFighter = new Model();

//AI_METHOD STARTING

    javaFighter.KI();

// other stuff to handle buttons, etc. This all works fine, so I don't think I // have to show it to you

}
```

I expected the AI-Method running until either the player or the enemy has won the game and while the AI-Method is running and attacking the player, the player can still input his attacks, etc.

The program crashed, as soon as it started the AI-Method.
The times, the program didn't crash, the Timer-Loop didn't let me input anything else, so I had to close the program.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting no error, because the program is still running, but it's not responsive anymore, when I start the AI-Method, so I have to close the window or my program by myself every time.

Comment: I can't tell if this is indeed true, but I bet those fields are not properly declared to work with multiple threads. Even if this isn't an issue, I expect a large amount of `Timer`s/`TimerTask`s to be created while you wait for the first 1 or 2 tasks that are actually scheduled to finish...

Comment: Yes I think that's the Problem. But I don't know how to code it, make it work, how I want it. I did a workaround and changed the code to activate only one Timer each time the player attacks by 50%/50% change. It works, but not exactly how I wanted it. Now the enemy only has the chance to attack, if you attacked him first. I balanced my game around that fact, but I think it should be possible somehow, to let something work in the background, while you can Input something else. Now it's like a queue and not a loop, which works only because of player input.